# SQL query for many to many DB in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

SQL query to show all tool_tip_links related to pages_learn_more ID?

How do I structure this query correctly?

```
 $SQL = 
    "SELECT ptt.tool_tip_link
    FROM pages_tool_tip ptt
    JOIN pages_to_pages ptp
    ON ptp.tool_tip_id = ptt.tool_tip_id
    WHERE ptp.learn_more_id = 2";

    $result = mysql_query($SQL); // or die(mysql_error()); 


     while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
   $reference_keys   =     $db_field['tool_tip_link'];  
        }
      echo $reference_keys;
```

How do I combine these queries to make them clean and efficient? Thanks for the help..

--------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------
Using this code:

```
    "SELECT ptt.tool_tip_link
    FROM pages_tool_tip ptt
    JOIN pages_to_pages ptp
            ON ptp.tool_tip_id = ptt.tool_tip_id
    JOIN pages_learn_more plm
            ON plm.id = ptp.learn_more_id
    WHERE plm.id = 2";
```

Should Show me 3 tool_tip_links. However it is only returning the last field in the DB which is 4 -> LINK 4

[image]

So how do i get all of the links, not just the last one?
ty again..

--------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------

When I echo out mysql_num_rows it displays correctly stating 3 for id #2.

So what code do I need to display all three rows links? LOOP ARRAY? **I don't get it because It should already be looped in my array**. Can i just echo `$reference_keys` or should I be doing something different?

I also tried a `foreach` and that returned an error. What am i doing wrong? please advise.

more db views --> hope it helps find a resolve..

[image: this is the pages_learn_more table]

[image: this is the pages tooltip table]

Comment: No sir, id2 displays LINK 4, ignoring LINK 2 and LINK 1

Comment: Can you please clean your question, remove unnecessary lines of code and add exactly the code giving you the problem?

Comment: ok hang on -> working on it..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your criteria:

> SQL query to show all tool_tip_links related to pages_learn_more ID

Here you go

```sql
SELECT ptt.tool_tip_link
FROM pages_tool_tip ptt
JOIN pages_to_pages ptp
     ON ptp.tool_tip_id = ptt.tool_tip_id
WHERE ptp.learn_more_id = :id
```

`:id` is the variable here.

Comment: sorta works.. only gave back 1 of the 2 tool_tip_links associated with :id 1. I switched your variable for 1 and id 1 in pages_learn_more should show LINK 1 and LINK 2. However it only showed LINK 2  --->  Any ideas? ty for the help btw

Comment: @FabioAnselmo, I think now it should be okay

Comment: --> no change.. Same result.. :/

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try some things. Thanks for the help. If you have any ideas from experience what the problem 'could be' please advise. Ty

Comment: Ok I figured that it is only showing the last record in the database and ignoring the others. I will update my question

Comment: @FabioAnselmo, of course! The right solution is the one right in front of your nose! Updated :D

Comment: What do you mean? I'm a novice and I see you changed your query again. But it is still doing the same thing and the issue is persisting.

Comment: @FabioAnselmo, I was talking about myself, I missed the solution even though it was in front of my eyes. Please test the query using phpMyAdmin.. you must be doing something wrong with your PHP code

Comment: well my php code is above.. can you peek at it and advise me.. much appreciated!!  ty again. I will try in query in phpMyadmin - standby   YES IT WORKS IN PHPMYADMIN..

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your query to:

```
"SELECT ptt.tool_tip_link
    FROM pages_learn_more plm
    JOIN pages_to_pages ptp
        ON plm.id = ptp.learn_more_id
    JOIN pages_tool_tip ptt
        ON ptp.tool_tip_id = ptt.tool_tip_id
    WHERE plm.id = 2";
```

This makes the pages_learn_more the main table on your join, and finds what you want.